Kubuntu 24.04 "sometimes" crashes when closing windows (on seemingly random occasions)
When closing programs my Plasmashell crashes occasionally, I'd say about 0.5% of the time when it comes to most programs but about 95% when to comes to, for example, KeepassXC which minimizes on closing and goes to the system Tray. After a lot of searching I thought I had fixed the problem by removing a few unused and/or broken custom themes and Widgets from ~/.local/share/plasma.
While provoking a crash by closing Keepass this the output of journalctl -f | grep --line-buffered plasmashell:
emil ~ ➜ journalctl -f | grep --line-buffered plasmashell
Sep 17 19:58:18 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:18 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present")
Sep 17 19:58:18 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:19 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:19 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:20 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:20 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:21 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:21 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT2/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT2/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: QSortFilterProxyModel: inconsistent changes reported by source model
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT2/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT2/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: XMLHttpRequest: Using GET on a local file is dangerous and will be disabled by default in a future Qt version.Set QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ to 1 if you wish to continue using this feature.
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: Failed to create a synchronous XHR for QUrl("file:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present")
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: kf.kio.widgets: REASON: "The file or folder /sys/class/power_supply/BAT3/present does not exist."
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 25 -- exe=/usr/bin/plasmashell
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 17 -- platform=wayland
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 20 -- appname=plasmashell
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 17 -- apppath=/usr/bin
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 10 -- signal=11
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 10 -- pid=22207
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 19 -- appversion=5.27.11
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 19 -- programname=Plasma
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: 31 -- bugaddress=submit@bugs.kde.org
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 22207
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell --no-respawn
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 17 and type 'Read', disabling...
Sep 17 19:58:22 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 19 and type 'Read', disabling...
Sep 17 19:58:23 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Sep 17 19:58:23 kubuntu-leptop plasmashell[22207]: Re-raising signal for core dump handling.

Then running coredumpctl to find the right (automatically generated) coredump:
emil ~ ➜ coredumpctl
TIME                            PID  UID  GID SIG     COREFILE     EXE                                SIZE
[others]
Mon 2024-09-16 18:56:45 CEST   5595 1000 1000 SIGABRT present      /usr/bin/plasmashell              81.3M
[others]

and then using coredumpctl gdb [PID] produces the following output: see gist
I don't think posting the entire (1.4 GB uncompressed) coredump is safe.
The Crash Handler GUI Application also openes only around 10% of the time and when it does its full of [New LWP [4 digit number]] as seen at the bottom of the coredumpctl gdb command. Scrolling further down the Developer Information dialog causes the crash handler to become unresponsive and crash.

I had a similar issues today. Turns out it was caused by a Widget I added called Power Monitor which for whatever reason caused KDE to glitch the hell out. Do you have any Widget like that installed or on your task manager? If you do try removing it from the task manager and see if it fixes it. It seems like something about trying to access the battery file or whatever causes weird issues. Hope that helps or at least gives a starting point

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't ask for clarification of a question in a answer. You will be able to ask in a comment when you have earned a reputation of 50 You will also earn a badge when you read that entire tour page.

Thanks a lot! No way it was that simple. I now just removed the widget entirely and everything seems to work fine now.
